# Overlapping a line plot to a horizontal bar plot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart

I'm trying to overlap a line plot to a horizontal bar plot in pandas.

Having a dataframe like this

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

I can overlap a plot to a bar plot, like this:

```
ax = data[['A','B','C']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
data['D'].plot(color='k',ax=ax)
```

with this result

[Plot on a bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23ZC1.png)

But when I try to use a horizontal barplot

```
ax = data['D'].plot(color='k')
data[['A','B','C']].plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, ax=ax)
```

I have this result

[Plot on a barh plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST2sw.png)

How can I flip the line plot so to have it coherent with the barh plot=

Thank you for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the index and plot as follows. Here I am using the values of `D` column as x-values and the `index` (range of values) as the y-values. By using `reset_index()` you add a column of index which makes using `y='index'` straightforward for your plotting purpose.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD')).reset_index()
ax = data.plot(x='D', y='index', color='k', legend=False)
data[['A','B','C']].plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, ax=ax)
```

**Output**

[image]